# Laravel Eloquent find all records where a date is within a range in JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use Eloquent to query a table of records in the database and only retrieve those records where at least 1 record in a json column, consisting of an array of objects, is within a given date range.

The dates column would look as follows:

```
[
  {'date': '2021-01-01'},
  {'date': '2021-01-02'},
  {'date': '2021-01-03'},
]
```

If I pass a start date of '2021-01-01' it then needs to fetch all records where dates.*.date is equal to or after this start date.

The same applies to the an end_date.

I've different kinds of syntax like:

```
$this->where('dates->[*]->date', '<=', date($value));
$this->where('dates->*->date', '<=', date($value));
$this->where('dates.*.date', '<=', date($value));
```

Nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which MySql version are you using? In 8.x you could the [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function to extract your date array into a table and perform the query on that

Comment: if nothing works, just do it through PHP.

You can create the index of dates and then match against that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) is probably the only (good) pure SQL way of doing this. This requires MySQL 8.0.4 or later. Here it is with Eloquent:

```php
$this->whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->fromRaw(
            'json_table(json_extract(`dates`, "$[*].date"), "$[*]" columns(`json_date` date path "$")) as `sub`'
        )
        ->where('json_date','>=','2021-01-01');
    })->get();
```

Explanation:

`json_extract` with `$[*].date` as the path parameter turns the data into a regular array `["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"]`)

`json_table` turns json data into regular sql rows:

| json_date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-01-03 |

The where clauses are applied and filters the resulting rows down to just those that have an existing `json_date` row in the json table.

Comment: I certainly don’t know; I’m not sure if I missed something? Other answers don’t take date ranges and multiple dates per row/json column into account, which is why I suggested `json_table`.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a working example?

Comment: What I would do is to create a scope on the model that lets you query the dates without writing that raw sql every time: https://gist.github.com/LowSociety/4ef7a901b8733a7d3d359fad82c7b6c7

Then query the model like this: https://gist.github.com/LowSociety/921c8cf91ba613180043075c479ae080

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `whereJsonContains` second param as array

```
Model::whereJsonContains('dates',['date'=>'2018-01-01'])->get();
```

Comment: But this will look for an exact match?! How do I return all dates which are 2018-01-01 and after/before that?

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen.yes ur right.i tried many ways to less than or greater but couldn't succeeded .if i get time i will check again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a raw SQL version, I don't know Eloquent well but I'm pretty sure you can execute raw SQL.

Here is your table

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable(id int, dates varchar(100));
INSERT INTO MyTable(id, dates) values(1, '[{"date": "2020-01-01"},{"date": "2020-01-02"},{"date": "2020-01-03"}]');
INSERT INTO MyTable(id, dates) values(2, '[{"date": "2021-01-01"},{"date": "2021-01-02"},{"date": "2021-01-03"}]');
INSERT INTO MyTable(id, dates) values(3, '[{"date": "2022-01-01"},{"date": "2022-01-02"},{"date": "2022-01-03"}]');
```

You can use this SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM JSON_TABLE(
            JSON_EXTRACT(dates, "$[*].date")
            , "$[*]" 
            COLUMNS(jsondate date path '$'
        )
    ) as fn 
    WHERE jsondate >= '2021-06-01'
);
```

The parent query is actually straight forward, but the subquery is more complex. It first use the [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function from MySQL which take JSON and a "path" to designate which values JSON to return : in our case every `date` field in our json objects, for example for the first row, it will return : `["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"]`.

With this JSON array you can now use the [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function to create a anonymous table, which also take JSON and the definition of your new table. We now have a table where one column `jsondate` where each row is one date, therefore we can use a simple WHERE clause to check if the date is greater than the one you want.

[Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kDzUMdRmXpFKsgJjqmAgMY/0)

Answer (score 0):

You should try **whereRaw** with **JSON_EXTRACT** -

```
$this->whereRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(`dates` , "$[*].date") <= ?', [date($value)]);
```

I think this will work in your case, please try and let me know if it worked.

Code link - [https://phpsandbox.io/n/calm-term-y1yo-upqak](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths)

to run the code please open tinker in terminal using

```
php artisan tinker

app(App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class)->testingJsonExtract()
```

For your reference - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `orWhereJsonContains()` constraints

```
$query->where(function ($query) use ($dates) {
   foreach ($dates as $date) {
       $query->orWhereJsonContains('dates', ['date' => $date]);
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work if you only pass a start or end date.

Comment: You will need to loop through the dates. 
`$dates = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2010-10-01'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2010-10-05')
);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->whereDate("json_extract('dates', '$.date')", '>', $date)->get();
```

As you can see above, I used `json_extract()` method which is MySQL's function to extract a field from JSON column since I can not simply instruct eloquent using arrow operator.

```
$this->whereDate('dates->date', '>', $date)->get();
```

Rather I have to explicitly tell eloquent to extract json field and then proceed.

Comment: This would assume that there's a direct child called date of dates but dates is an array of objects.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen, try using `$[*].date` instead

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
Model::whereJsonContains('dates', ['starts_at' => '2021-01-01'])->get();
```

Similarly, for dates upto a value:

```
Model::whereJsonContains('dates', ['ends_at' => '2021-01-01'])->get();
```